# ASPxGridView Master Detail Export to Excel - Detail Export not correct

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have one aspxgridview in aspx page and its datasource getting my procedure return 2 table. Datasource generated detail grid automatically because second table. But when I get excel export detail grids not export.

My cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ASPxGridView1.DataSource = mydatatable;
     ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void btnGridToExcell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ASPxGridView1.SettingsDetail.ExportMode = DevExpress.Web.GridViewDetailExportMode.All;
    ASPxGridViewExporter1.WriteXlsxToResponse(new XlsxExportOptionsEx() { ExportType = ExportType.WYSIWYG });
}
```

aspx code

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="ASPxGridView1" OnCustomCallback="ASPxGridView1_CustomCallback" >
            <SettingsDetail ShowDetailRow="true" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the master **ASPxGridView.SettingsDetail.ExportMode** to Expanded/All and populate the detail grid with the actual/related/filtered data:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" ...>
    <SettingsDetail ShowDetailRow="true" ExportMode="All" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Check out [this](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Exporting/ExportDetails.aspx) demo to see this feature/approach in action.

Comment: My problem I can't use OnBeforePerformDataSelect event because of my detail grids generated from stored procedure